# Organizing data by using sapply and grep to group data by row name?

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
EUR.DATE EUR.HIGH EUR.LOW EUR.CLOSE EUR.OPEN EUR.20D EUR.50D JPY.DATE JPY. HIGH...
01/01    1.3133, 1.3128, 1.3132, 1.3182, 1.327, 1.3282, 1.3294, 01/01   112...
```

Sample dput is attached below:

```
structure(list(EUR.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 
1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), EUR.HIGH = c(1.316, 1.3137, 1.3145, 1.3196, 1.3221
), EUR.LOW = c(1.3122, 1.311, 1.3119, 1.3132, 1.316), EUR.OPEN = c(1.3133, 
1.3128, 1.3138, 1.3182, 1.3193), EUR.CLOSE = c(1.315, 1.3133, 
1.3128, 1.3132, 1.3182), EUR.20D = c(1.327, 1.3282, 1.3294, 1.3309, 
1.3323), EUR.50D = c(1.3427, 1.3436, 1.3446, 1.3455, 1.3465), 
    JPY.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    JPY.HIGH = c(105.31, 105.21, 104.35, 104.11, 103.92), JPY.LOW = c(104.74, 
    104.3, 104.06, 103.66, 103.56), JPY.OPEN = c(105.09, 104.35, 
    104.08, 103.72, 103.88), JPY.CLOSE = c(104.79, 105.09, 104.35, 
    104.09, 103.72), JPY.20D = c(103.34, 103.21, 103.09, 103, 
    102.92), JPY.50D = c(102.43, 102.37, 102.31, 102.26, 102.22
    ), GBP.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    GBP.HIGH = c(1.6497, 1.6615, 1.6644, 1.6614, 1.6614), GBP.LOW = c(1.644, 
    1.6468, 1.6586, 1.6563, 1.6567), GBP.OPEN = c(1.647, 1.6608, 
    1.6593, 1.6586, 1.6576), GBP.CLOSE = c(1.6461, 1.647, 1.6608, 
    1.6598, 1.6586), GBP.20D = c(1.6639, 1.6659, 1.668, 1.6692, 
    1.6703), GBP.50D = c(1.6882, 1.6892, 1.6903, 1.6911, 1.6919
    ), CHF.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CHF.HIGH = c(0.9201, 0.9212, 0.9198, 0.9184, 0.9162), CHF.LOW = c(0.9176, 
    0.9188, 0.9177, 0.9139, 0.9126), CHF.HIGH.1 = c(0.919, 0.9196, 
    0.9179, 0.9151, 0.9148), CHF.OPEN = c(0.9177, 0.919, 0.9196, 
    0.9182, 0.9151), CHF.CLOSE = c(0.9118, 0.9113, 0.9108, 0.9102, 
    0.9096), CHF50D = c(0.9037, 0.9032, 0.9027, 0.9022, 0.9017
    ), AUD.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    AUD.HIGH = c(0.9351, 0.9337, 0.9352, 0.9363, 0.9374), AUD.LOW = c(0.9263, 
    0.9268, 0.9319, 0.9332, 0.9332), AUD.OPEN = c(0.9274, 0.9332, 
    0.9329, 0.9357, 0.9337), AUD.CLOSE = c(0.9347, 0.9274, 0.9332, 
    0.9339, 0.9357), AUD.20D = c(0.9307, 0.9308, 0.9309, 0.9309, 
    0.9308), AUD.50D = c(0.9354, 0.9355, 0.9357, 0.9358, 0.9359
    ), CAD.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CAD.HIGH = c(1.0943, 1.0935, 1.0878, 1.0879, 1.0869), CAD.LOW = c(1.0871, 
    1.0867, 1.0857, 1.0811, 1.0837), CAD.OPEN = c(1.0929, 1.0871, 
    1.0869, 1.0861, 1.0865), CAD.CLOSE = c(1.0888, 1.0929, 1.0871, 
    1.0878, 1.0861), CAD.20D = c(1.0918, 1.092, 1.0921, 1.0923, 
    1.0925), CAD.50D = c(1.082, 1.0817, 1.0813, 1.081, 1.0808
    ), NZD.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    NZD.HIGH = c(0.8332, 0.8391, 0.8389, 0.8398, 0.8408), NZD.LOW = c(0.8288, 
    0.8292, 0.8348, 0.8356, 0.8364), NZD.OPEN = c(0.8316, 0.8377, 
    0.8356, 0.8383, 0.8374), NZD.CLOSE = c(0.8326, 0.8316, 0.8377, 
    0.8362, 0.8383), NZD.20D = c(0.8408, 0.8416, 0.8424, 0.8431, 
    0.8439), NZD.50D = c(0.8568, 0.8576, 0.8583, 0.859, 0.8596
    ), SEK.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    SEK.HIGH = c(7.0249, 7.0242, 7.0346, 6.9967, 6.9859), SEK.LOW = c(6.9894, 
    6.9945, 6.9795, 6.943, 6.9279), SEK.CLOSE = c(7.0167, 7.0045, 
    6.9795, 6.9717, 6.9495), SEK.OPEN = c(7.0038, 7.0167, 7.0045, 
    6.9918, 6.9717), SEK.20D = c(6.9201, 6.9146, 6.908, 6.9019, 
    6.8953), SEK.50D = c(6.8588, 6.8534, 6.8476, 6.8414, 6.8358
    ), NOK.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    NOK.HIGH = c(6.2314, 6.2054, 6.2094, 6.2021, 6.1938), NOK.LOW = c(6.1855, 
    6.1832, 6.1776, 6.1697, 6.166), NOK.OPEN = c(6.1874, 6.1919, 
    6.1939, 6.1795, 6.1804), NOK.CLOSE = c(6.2179, 6.1874, 6.1919, 
    6.1975, 6.1795), NOK.20D = c(7.5563, 7.5738, 7.5975, 7.5975, 
    7.5975), NOK.50D = c(6.1941, 6.1924, 6.1909, 6.1892, 6.1876
    ), CZK.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CZK.HIGH = c(21.1358, 21.2163, 21.1489, 21.1551, 21.1434), 
    CZK.LOW = c(21.017, 21.1095, 21.0906, 21.013, 20.9375), CZK.OPEN = c(21.1247, 
    21.1359, 21.1065, 21.1101, 20.9924), CZK.CLOSE = c(21.0528, 
    21.1247, 21.1359, 21.1194, 21.11), CZK.20D = c(21.1247, 21.1359, 
    21.1065, 21.1101, 20.9924), CZK.50D = c(21.0528, 21.1247, 
    21.1359, 21.1194, 21.11), HUF.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 
    1409634000, 1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), HUF.HIGH = c(240.5, 240.92, 240.55, 
    240.35, 240.3), HUF.LOW = c(238.35, 239.2, 238.96, 238.51, 
    236.56), HUF.HIGH.1 = c(240.31, 239.49, 240.09, 239.06, 237
    ), HUF.LOW.1 = c(238.76, 240.31, 239.49, 239.77, 239.06), 
    HUF.20D = c(236.55, 236.41, 236.2, 235.9, 235.57), HUF.50D = c(232.32, 
    232.05, 231.74, 231.44, 231.14), ILS.DATE = structure(c(1409115600, 
    1409029200, 1408942800, 1408683600, 1408597200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ILS.HIGH = c(3.576, 3.588, 3.5775, 
    3.543, 3.5505), ILS.LOW = c(3.5615, 3.563, 3.534, 3.514, 
    3.5185), ILS.HIGH.1 = c(3.5703, 3.579, 3.5345, 3.525, 3.545
    ), ILS.LOW.1 = c(3.563, 3.57, 3.5705, 3.533, 3.526), ILS.20D = c(3.4915, 
    3.4849, 3.4779, 3.4707, 3.4654), ILS.50D = c(3.4526, 3.4503, 
    3.4481, 3.4458, 3.4442), PLN.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 
    1409634000, 1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), PLN.HIGH = c(3.2095, 3.2148, 3.213, 
    3.2164, 3.2101), PLN.LOW = c(3.182, 3.2005, 3.2003, 3.193, 
    3.1767), PLN.HIGH.1 = c(3.2058, 3.2017, 3.2089, 3.2036, 3.1831
    ), PLN.LOW.1 = c(3.1909, 3.2058, 3.2017, 3.2056, 3.2036), 
    PLN.20D = c(3.1628, 3.1603, 3.1565, 3.152, 3.1475), PLN.50D = c(3.1061, 
    3.103, 3.1, 3.0971, 3.0943), RUB.DATE = structure(c(1406696400, 
    1406610000, 1406523600, 1406264400, 1406178000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), RUB.HIGH = c(35.9303, 35.758, 35.56, 
    35.1373, 35.1463), RUB.LOW = c(35.4986, 35.5684, 35.2557, 
    35.0105, 34.9402), RUB.HIGH.1 = c(35.9106, 35.6705, 35.2578, 
    35.0906, 35.0165), RUB.LOW.1 = c(35.614, 35.6753, 35.5252, 
    35.0817, 35.0413), RUB.20D = c(34.7338, 34.6695, 34.6022, 
    34.5282, 34.4608), RUB.50D = c(34.5266, 34.5052, 34.4821, 
    34.4666, 34.4596), TRY.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 
    1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TRY.HIGH = c(2.1742, 2.1782, 2.1657, 
    2.1652, 2.1727), TRY.LOW = c(2.1563, 2.1595, 2.1569, 2.1537, 
    2.1536), TRY.LOW.1 = c(2.1725, 2.1602, 2.1619, 2.1581, 2.154
    ), TRY.HIGH.1 = c(2.1572, 2.1727, 2.1603, 2.163, 2.1581), 
    TRY.20D = c(2.1637, 2.1638, 2.1628, 2.1613, 2.1599), TRY.50D = c(2.1392, 
    2.1387, 2.1381, 2.1376, 2.1372), ZAR.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 
    1409634000, 1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ZAR.HIGH = c(10.748, 10.7486, 10.6852, 
    10.6735, 10.6868), ZAR.LOW = c(10.6707, 10.6713, 10.6448, 
    10.5904, 10.6034), ZAR.HIGH.1 = c(10.7402, 10.6747, 10.6636, 
    10.6511, 10.6129), ZAR.LOW.1 = c(10.6886, 10.7402, 10.6747, 
    10.6666, 10.6511), ZAR.20D = c(10.6601, 10.6608, 10.6616, 
    10.6606, 10.6612), ZAR.50D = c(10.6612, 10.6593, 10.6573, 
    10.6558, 10.6554), BRL.DATE = structure(c(1406869200, 1406782800, 
    1406696400, 1406610000, 1406523600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), BRL.HIGH = c(2.282, 2.2748, 2.26, 
    2.2321, 2.2348), BRL.LOW = c(2.2508, 2.253, 2.233, 2.224, 
    2.2222), BRL.HIGH.1 = c(2.2723, 2.2551, 2.2366, 2.2276, 2.2294
    ), BRL.LOW.1 = c(2.2573, 2.2638, 2.2456, 2.2315, 2.2225), 
    BRL.20D = c(2.2279, 2.2261, 2.2234, 2.2224, 2.2209), BRL.50D = c(2.2301, 
    2.2293, 2.2282, 2.2276, 2.2271), CLP.DATE = structure(c(1406091600, 
    1406005200, 1405918800, 1405659600, 1405573200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CLP.HIGH = c(568.55, 568.55, 568.55, 
    568.56, 565.75), CLP.LOW = c(562.82, 562.16, 559.45, 564.55, 
    557.75), CLP.HIGH.1 = c(564.51, 563.91, 568.55, 564.8, 559.51
    ), CLP.LOW.1 = c(563.57, 564.65, 564.57, 567.61, 564.54), 
    CLP.20D = c(555.58, 554.99, 554.39, 553.96, 553.43), CLP.50D = c(554.1, 
    553.87, 553.69, 553.47, 553.42), COP.DATE = structure(c(1406264400, 
    1406178000, 1406091600, 1406005200, 1405918800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), COP.HIGH = c(1849.5, 1847.5, 1847.7, 
    1856.5, 1868.5), COP.LOW = c(1846.5, 1842.76, 1845.5, 1856.5, 
    1866.7), COP.OPEN = c(1847.7, 1842.76, 1847.7, 1856.5, 1866.7
    ), COP.CLOSE = c(1849.5, 1846.5, 1846.5, 1856.5, 1868.5), 
    COP.20D = c(1860.69, 1862.74, 1864.64, 1866.49, 1867.79), 
    COP.50D = c(1884.4, 1885.48, 1886.76, 1888.04, 1889.27), 
    MXN.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    MXN.HIGH = c(13.1196, 13.1476, 13.0999, 13.1009, 13.1309), 
    MXN.LOW = c(13.0732, 13.0912, 13.0575, 13.0464, 13.0689), 
    MXN.HIGH.1 = c(13.109, 13.0959, 13.0633, 13.0856, 13.0844
    ), MXN.LOW.1 = c(13.0986, 13.109, 13.0959, 13.0847, 13.0856
    ), MXN.20D = c(13.1203, 13.1271, 13.1363, 13.1413, 13.1462
    ), MXN.50D = c(13.0609, 13.059, 13.058, 13.0567, 13.0548), 
    PEN.DATE = structure(c(1407214800, 1407128400, 1406869200, 
    1406782800, 1406696400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    PEN.HIGH = c(2.816, 2.8091, 2.799, 2.802, 2.7935), PEN.LOW = c(2.8089, 
    2.7973, 2.795, 2.7926, 2.7866), PEN.LOW.1 = c(2.8128, 2.7983, 
    2.798, 2.793, 2.7873), PEN.HIGH.1 = c(2.8149, 2.808, 2.7982, 
    2.8011, 2.7895), PEN.20D = c(2.79, 2.7881, 2.7862, 2.7851, 
    2.7846), PEN.50D = c(2.7899, 2.7893, 2.7889, 2.7887, 2.7885
    ), CNY.DATE = structure(c(1404277200, 1404190800, 1404104400, 
    1403845200, 1403758800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CNY.HIGH = c(6.2134, 6.2066, 6.2167, 6.2258, 6.2337), CNY.LOW = c(6.198, 
    6.1973, 6.2, 6.216, 6.2243), CNY.OPEN = c(6.198, 6.2023, 
    6.2166, 6.2258, 6.229), CNY.CLOSE = c(6.2101, 6.2009, 6.2033, 
    6.2179, 6.2248), CNY.20D = c(6.2256, 6.2276, 6.2303, 6.2325, 
    6.2336), CNY.50D = c(6.2344, 6.2347, 6.2351, 6.2354, 6.2355
    ), IDR.DATE = structure(c(1405314000, 1405054800, 1404968400, 
    1404795600, 1404709200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    IDR.HIGH = c(11670, 11637, 11595, 11781, 11870), IDR.LOW = c(11609, 
    11579, 11513, 11605, 11683), IDR.HIGH.1 = c(11610, 11605, 
    11571, 11708, 11829), IDR.LOW.1 = c(11670, 11590, 11580, 
    11630, 11710), IDR.20D = c(11869, 11876, 11886, 11897, 11906
    ), IDR.50D = c(11724, 11722, 11722, 11722, 11722), INR.DATE = structure(c(1402981200, 
    1402894800, 1402635600, 1402549200, 1402462800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), INR.HIGH = c(60.525, 60.225, 59.8, 
    59.3625, 59.36), INR.LOW = c(60.35, 59.84, 59.3037, 59.325, 
    59.325), INR.HIGH.1 = c(59.1977, 59.1287, 59.0502, 59.0007, 
    59.0025), INR.LOW.1 = c(59.7126, 59.7186, 59.7186, 59.7327, 
    59.7634), X67.7266 = c(62.8711, 62.8345, 62.7951, 62.7951, 
    62.7951), INR.20D = c(1031.35, 1029.65, 1030.57, 1032.55, 
    1041.23), INR.50D = c(1031, 1028.9, 1029.28, 1030.5, 1037
    ), KRW.DATE = structure(c(1407992400, 1407906000, 1407819600, 
    1407733200, 1407474000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    KRW.HIGH = c(1028.77, 1029.18, 1029.31, 1029.35, 1028.73), 
    KRW.LOW = c(1021.92, 1021.91, 1021.78, 1021.72, 1021.58), 
    KRW.HIGH.1 = c(3.205, 3.2137, 3.1978, 3.184, 3.1748), KRW.LOW.1 = c(3.205, 
    3.208, 3.1805, 3.1745, 3.1745), KRW.20D = c(3.1813, 3.1806, 
    3.1793, 3.1793, 3.1805), KRW.50D = c(3.2015, 3.2017, 3.2017, 
    3.202, 3.2027)), .Names = c("EUR.DATE", "EUR.HIGH", "EUR.LOW", 
"EUR.OPEN", "EUR.CLOSE", "EUR.20D", "EUR.50D", "JPY.DATE", "JPY.HIGH", 
"JPY.LOW", "JPY.OPEN", "JPY.CLOSE", "JPY.20D", "JPY.50D", "GBP.DATE", 
"GBP.HIGH", "GBP.LOW", "GBP.OPEN", "GBP.CLOSE", "GBP.20D", "GBP.50D", 
"CHF.DATE", "CHF.HIGH", "CHF.LOW", "CHF.HIGH.1", "CHF.OPEN", 
"CHF.CLOSE", "CHF50D", "AUD.DATE", "AUD.HIGH", "AUD.LOW", "AUD.OPEN", 
"AUD.CLOSE", "AUD.20D", "AUD.50D", "CAD.DATE", "CAD.HIGH", "CAD.LOW", 
"CAD.OPEN", "CAD.CLOSE", "CAD.20D", "CAD.50D", "NZD.DATE", "NZD.HIGH", 
"NZD.LOW", "NZD.OPEN", "NZD.CLOSE", "NZD.20D", "NZD.50D", "SEK.DATE", 
"SEK.HIGH", "SEK.LOW", "SEK.CLOSE", "SEK.OPEN", "SEK.20D", "SEK.50D", 
"NOK.DATE", "NOK.HIGH", "NOK.LOW", "NOK.OPEN", "NOK.CLOSE", "NOK.20D", 
"NOK.50D", "CZK.DATE", "CZK.HIGH", "CZK.LOW", "CZK.OPEN", "CZK.CLOSE", 
"CZK.20D", "CZK.50D", "HUF.DATE", "HUF.HIGH", "HUF.LOW", "HUF.HIGH.1", 
"HUF.LOW.1", "HUF.20D", "HUF.50D", "ILS.DATE", "ILS.HIGH", "ILS.LOW", 
"ILS.HIGH.1", "ILS.LOW.1", "ILS.20D", "ILS.50D", "PLN.DATE", 
"PLN.HIGH", "PLN.LOW", "PLN.HIGH.1", "PLN.LOW.1", "PLN.20D", 
"PLN.50D", "RUB.DATE", "RUB.HIGH", "RUB.LOW", "RUB.HIGH.1", "RUB.LOW.1", 
"RUB.20D", "RUB.50D", "TRY.DATE", "TRY.HIGH", "TRY.LOW", "TRY.LOW.1", 
"TRY.HIGH.1", "TRY.20D", "TRY.50D", "ZAR.DATE", "ZAR.HIGH", "ZAR.LOW", 
"ZAR.HIGH.1", "ZAR.LOW.1", "ZAR.20D", "ZAR.50D", "BRL.DATE", 
"BRL.HIGH", "BRL.LOW", "BRL.HIGH.1", "BRL.LOW.1", "BRL.20D", 
"BRL.50D", "CLP.DATE", "CLP.HIGH", "CLP.LOW", "CLP.HIGH.1", "CLP.LOW.1", 
"CLP.20D", "CLP.50D", "COP.DATE", "COP.HIGH", "COP.LOW", "COP.OPEN", 
"COP.CLOSE", "COP.20D", "COP.50D", "MXN.DATE", "MXN.HIGH", "MXN.LOW", 
"MXN.HIGH.1", "MXN.LOW.1", "MXN.20D", "MXN.50D", "PEN.DATE", 
"PEN.HIGH", "PEN.LOW", "PEN.LOW.1", "PEN.HIGH.1", "PEN.20D", 
"PEN.50D", "CNY.DATE", "CNY.HIGH", "CNY.LOW", "CNY.OPEN", "CNY.CLOSE", 
"CNY.20D", "CNY.50D", "IDR.DATE", "IDR.HIGH", "IDR.LOW", "IDR.HIGH.1", 
"IDR.LOW.1", "IDR.20D", "IDR.50D", "INR.DATE", "INR.HIGH", "INR.LOW", 
"INR.HIGH.1", "INR.LOW.1", "X67.7266", "INR.20D", "INR.50D", 
"KRW.DATE", "KRW.HIGH", "KRW.LOW", "KRW.HIGH.1", "KRW.LOW.1", 
"KRW.20D", "KRW.50D"), row.names = 647:651, class = "data.frame")
```

And I'm trying to use the following code to group my data into a list of dataframes ordered by currency such that:
    cur<-c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 
           'PLN', 'RUB', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 
           'KRW')
    i <- sapply(cur, function(y) grep(paste0("^", y),names(x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    MergedData <- sapply(i, function(i) x[i])

Where x is from the sample dput. However, this returns

```
MergedData[[1]]
Eur.Date  Eur.High Eur.Low Eur.Open Eur.Close Eur.20D  Eur.50D
01/01     
MergedData[[2]]
JPY.Date JPY.High JPY.Low JPY.Open JPY.Close
```

But instead the code is returning

```
$Eur.Date
[1] "2017-02-23 CST" "2017-02-22 CST" "2017-02-21 CST" "2017-02-20 CST" "2017-02-17 CST"
```

And so on. I had the code working before, until I changed a few wrongly named variables in Excel (my original data is from Excel). Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your dput does not actually include the currency names. Are you manually attaching them to your data.frame? Also, I am not quite sure what this code is doing `i <- sapply(cur, function(y) grep(paste0("^", y),names(x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
MergedData <- sapply(i, function(i) x[i])` Which `x` in `x[i]` are you referring to in this last line?

Comment: @useR Oh I apologize. x is actually referring to my raw import. I'm also realizing that in my haste I had attached the dput for the transformed data. Edited and fixed this. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is pretty close actually, but you should use `lapply`, which returns a list instead of `sapply`, which returns a vector.

```
# Currencies
cur = c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 
       'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'PLN', 'RUB', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 
       'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 'KRW')

# Extracts the index of columns that corresponds to each cur
ii = sapply(cur, function(y) grep(paste0("^", y), names(df)))
```

This creates a matrix `ii` with columns corresponding to each currency, and rows corresponding to the column indices.

```
# Use ii as index to split data.frame into lists of data.frames.
mergedData = lapply(as.data.frame(ii), function(x) df[x])
```

Here, I converted the matrix `ii` into a data.frame with `as.data.frame`, because `lapply` (or `sapply` for that matter), applies the function to each element of the list provided. And since `data.frames` *are* lists with columns corresponding to elements of a list, `ii[1]` means the first *column* of `ii`. If you don't do the conversion, `lapply` will apply the function to the matrix `ii`. So `ii[1]` in this case actually means the first *element* of `ii`, which is not what we want.

Sample output

```
# $EUR
# EUR.DATE EUR.HIGH EUR.LOW EUR.OPEN EUR.CLOSE EUR.20D EUR.50D
# 647 2014-09-03 01:00:00   1.3160  1.3122   1.3133    1.3150  1.3270  1.3427
# 648 2014-09-02 01:00:00   1.3137  1.3110   1.3128    1.3133  1.3282  1.3436
# 649 2014-09-01 01:00:00   1.3145  1.3119   1.3138    1.3128  1.3294  1.3446
# 650 2014-08-29 01:00:00   1.3196  1.3132   1.3182    1.3132  1.3309  1.3455
# 651 2014-08-28 01:00:00   1.3221  1.3160   1.3193    1.3182  1.3323  1.3465
# 
# $JPY
# JPY.DATE JPY.HIGH JPY.LOW JPY.OPEN JPY.CLOSE JPY.20D JPY.50D
# 647 2014-09-03 01:00:00   105.31  104.74   105.09    104.79  103.34  102.43
# 648 2014-09-02 01:00:00   105.21  104.30   104.35    105.09  103.21  102.37
# 649 2014-09-01 01:00:00   104.35  104.06   104.08    104.35  103.09  102.31
# 650 2014-08-29 01:00:00   104.11  103.66   103.72    104.09  103.00  102.26
# 651 2014-08-28 01:00:00   103.92  103.56   103.88    103.72  102.92  102.22
# 
# $GBP
# GBP.DATE GBP.HIGH GBP.LOW GBP.OPEN GBP.CLOSE GBP.20D GBP.50D
# 647 2014-09-03 01:00:00   1.6497  1.6440   1.6470    1.6461  1.6639  1.6882
# 648 2014-09-02 01:00:00   1.6615  1.6468   1.6608    1.6470  1.6659  1.6892
# 649 2014-09-01 01:00:00   1.6644  1.6586   1.6593    1.6608  1.6680  1.6903
# 650 2014-08-29 01:00:00   1.6614  1.6563   1.6586    1.6598  1.6692  1.6911
# 651 2014-08-28 01:00:00   1.6614  1.6567   1.6576    1.6586  1.6703  1.6919
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I'm getting the error saying df[x]: object of type closure is not subsettable

Comment: @Nikitau You have to set your data.frame equal to `df` for this to work. I think you called yours `x`.

Comment: I have set x as my dput above. Do you mean I need to set x = df?

Comment: @Nikitau I mean set `df` as your dput (`df = dput`). I used `df` instead of `x` so that it is less confusing. But `x` works too if you change the `df` in my code to `x`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting df as my dput, but for some reason I'm getting different output from you. My MergedData is returning  

EUR         JPY         GBP         CHF         AUD         CAD         NZD           
EUR.DATE  Numeric,651 Numeric,651 Numeric,651 Numeric,651 EUR. EUR. HIGH
EUR. LOW Numeric,651 Numeric,651 Numeric,651 Numeric,651

Comment: @Nikitau Did you use my code exactly as it is written? You should first set `df = duput above`, then copy my code exactly. If it still doesn't work, try clearing your work space and try again.

Comment: Thanks! Silly me, it was something already in my space that was interfering. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Nikitau Glad that it helps. If this answered your question, please accept it so others can see.